# Why do I still have a right margin when I have it set to 0 all around?

Tags: css

I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpufo/tctznh73/1/) so that you can see what I am talking about. What I want is to have the "empty cart" button to be right under total, but for some reason there is a right-margin pushing it out of place. I have the margin set to zero for that element and I don't see it being overwritten in the inspector, yet there is still a right margin. If I try to float it to the right, the margin goes away, but it messes up the placement of the button under it. Also another problem I am having is the last shop item with the img missing. It is out of place for some reason. I haven't been able to figure out why it is slightly below the others.

Here is the styles for the empty cart button:

```
#emptyCartBtn{
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.67em;
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is it in html

```
<div id="cartBottom">
  <label id="total">
    <span>Total: $</span><span>0.00</span>
  </label>
  <input type="button" value="Empty Cart" id="emptyCartBtn" >
  <input type="button" value="Confirm Purchase" id="purchaseBtn">
</div>
```

Also here is the styles for my shop items:

```
.ShopItem{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #32C996;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your pineapple text is two lines long while the strawberry text is one, causing them to not line up. Make your pineapple text only one line and it will fix the problem with the strawberry item not lining up.

Comment: I fixed it by adding margin-left to the button mentioned above. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tctznh73/3/).

Comment: @Darkisa Thanks, you are right about the two lines of text causing the Shop Item to be out of place. If I wanted to keep the two lines of text, is there a way to have it not effect the layout?

Comment: The quickest way I can think of would be to set a minimum height for the labels in your css e.g. label{ min-height: 50px }. Then, because the height of the labels increased, the elements below your labels will be pushed down slightly to the bottom of your DIVs. In which case, you will just need to expand your DIVs slightly or make the elements below your labels slightly smaller. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a margin creating that space. The label above it and the button are a lot wider than they appear on the page, and the label is `text-align: right`. If you remove `text-align` you'll see that the text aligns on the left side of the respective elements.

You can float those elements right, then `clear: right` so it doesn't mess up the layout. Then if you want the empty cart button to be flush with the elements above/below it, remove it's `padding` or just `padding-right` or whatever you want.

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
h1{
  background-color: #32C996;
  color: white;
  width: 210px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
h2{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
h4{
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
hr{
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.ShopItem{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #32C996;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.ShopItem img{
  height: 170px;
  width: 220px;
}
.fruitName{
 display: block;
font-weight: bold; 
}
.price{
  font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;
}
.stock{
  font-size: larger;
}
.inStock{
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.addToCartBtn{
  width: 190px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: larger;
  background-color: #32C996;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.cartItem{
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #6FD9B5;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}

.cartItem img{
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
.quantity{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.count{
  color: black;
  font-size: x-large;
}
.countBtn{
  /*width: 20px;
  height: 17px;*/
  font-size: large;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.bottomHalf{
  color: black;
}
.bottomHalf label{
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.deleteBtn{
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#mainContent{
  width: 1450px;
  min-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
}
#shop{
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#shoppingCart{
  color: white;
  min-width: 350px;
  background-color: #32C996;
}
#shoppingHead{
  text-align: center;
}
#total{
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 0.90em;
}
#emptyCartBtn{
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.67em;
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#purchaseBtn{
  width: 190px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #C0EFDF;
}
#cartBottom{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#container{
  border-top: 5px solid #32C996;
  width: 100%;
}

#cartBottom > * {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

#emptyCartBtn {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="app"><div data-reactid=".0"><h1 data-reactid=".0.0">Fruit</h1><div id="container" data-reactid=".0.1"><div id="mainContent" data-reactid=".0.1.0"><div id="shop" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0"><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0"><img src="" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.1">banana</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.0.1">1.25</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.1.0">10</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$0.3"></div><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1"><img src="" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.1">apple</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.0.1">2.5</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.1.0">5</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$1.3"></div><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2"><img src="" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.1">raspberry</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.0.1">4</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.1.0">2</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$2.3"></div><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3"><img src="" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.1">kiwi</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.0.1">3.33</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.1.0">15</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$3.3"></div><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4"><img src="" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.1">very delicious pineapple with a long name</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.0.1">4.75</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.1.0">1</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$4.3"></div><div class="ShopItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5"><img src="./no-image.png" class="shopImg" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.0"><label class="fruitName" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.1">strawberries</label><div class="inStock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2"><span class="price" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.0.0">$</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.0.1">2.05</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.0.2"> </span></span><span class="stock" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.1.0">3</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.2.1.1"> in Stock</span></span></div><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" class="addToCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$5.3"></div></div><div id="shoppingCart" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1"><div id="shoppingHead" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0"><h2 data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0">Shopping Cart</h2><h4 data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.1"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.1.0">2</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.1.1"> items</span></h4></div><div id="cart" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1"><div class="cartItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2"><div class="topHalf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0"><img src="" class="cartImg" width="80" height="60" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0.0"><div class="quantity" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0.1"><input type="button" value="-" class="countBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0.1.0"><label class="count" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0.1.1">0</label><input type="button" value="+" class="countBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.0.1.2"></div></div><div class="bottomHalf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1"><label data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.0.0">@ $</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.0.1">4</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.0.2">each = $</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.0.3">0.00</span></label><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$2.1.1"></div></div><div class="cartItem" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3"><div class="topHalf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0"><img src="" class="cartImg" width="80" height="60" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0.0"><div class="quantity" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0.1"><input type="button" value="-" class="countBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0.1.0"><label class="count" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0.1.1">0</label><input type="button" value="+" class="countBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.0.1.2"></div></div><div class="bottomHalf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1"><label data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.0.0">@ $</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.0.1">3.33</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.0.2">each = $</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.0.3">0.00</span></label><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.$3.1.1"></div></div></div><hr data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.2"><div id="cartBottom" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3"><label id="total" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3.0.0">Total: $</span><span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3.0.1">0.00</span></label><input type="button" value="Empty Cart" id="emptyCartBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3.1"><input type="button" value="Confirm Purchase" id="purchaseBtn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.3.2"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
    <script src="app.min.js"></script>
  

</body>
```